# On Asp.net Web Api authorization filters, how can I access to parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'am starting with Asp.Net Web API and here's my problem :

I implement a custom authorization filter to inspect my message header looking for an API Key. Based on this API Key, I retrieve my user and then I would like to see if he can have access to some resources. The resources ID I want to check is on the parameters of the HTTP request. But when I'am on the AuthorizationFilter method, the actions parameters list is empty.

How can I do that ?

If I used an ActionFilter in replacement of an authorization filter, how can I be sure that this will be the first filter executed ? And globally, how can I specify the executing order of filters ?

Last question, is it possible to add some data "on the pipe" that I could retrieve on any filter ? Something like a session store but limited to the request ?

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The authorization attributes run before parameter binding has run therefore you cannot (as you have seen) use the `ActionArguments` collection. Instead you will need to use the request uri for query parameters and route data for uri parameters as demonstrated below.

```cs
//request at http://localhost/api/foo/id?MyValue=1
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //will not work as parameter binding has not yet run
        object value;
        actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("id", out value);

        //Will get you the resource id assuming a default route like /api/foo/{id} 
        var routeData = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData();
        var myId = routeData.Values["id"] as string;

        //uri is still accessible so use this to get query params
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query);
        var myQueryParam = queryString["MyValue"];

        //and so on
    }
}
```

**About the execution order**:

There are 3 different ways of specifying the execution order of filters using the [FilterScope Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.filterscope%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)... scope being Global, Controller and Action. The `AuthoriseAttribute` is "Global" and therefore it

> Specifies an action before Controller.

If you needed to specify the execution order within these 3 scopes then you should read [this blog article](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/control-the-execution-order-of-your-filters-in-asp-net-web-api/) here where you will need to implement a `FilterProvider`

**To add some data to the pipe**:

Use the properties collection on the request this collection is available for the duration of the request.

```cs
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("__MYKEY__","MyValue");

        //access this later in the controller or other action filters using
        var value = actionContext.Request.Properties["__MYKEY__"];

    }
```

Comment: You can also get path parameter information from the RouteData.  If memory serves me, it would something like Request.GetRouteData().Values;

Comment: @DarrelMiller, I just followed up on that idea and my harness doesn't seem to work that way. var routeData = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData();
            var value = routeData.Values["MyValue"] as string;    My routeData only contains the controller value. Let me know if you disagree and I will investigate further.

Comment: Using first an authorization filter setting a value into request properties and then an action filter is working. Other information were useful too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarkJones  I just tried it with the default `/api/values/{id}` route and I was able to read `Id` from RouteData in the OnAuthorization event of an AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I thought the question was referring to query string params. Agree the Id would be available as you suggest though.

Comment: @DarrelMiller that was me misreading the question. Sorry. I will update to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to get to the parameters is to `Execute` the binding for the parameters.

```
try
{
    var binding = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding;
    var parameters = binding.ParameterBindings.OfType<ModelBinderParameterBinding>();
    var newBinding = new HttpActionBinding(actionContext.ActionDescriptor, parameters.ToArray());
    newBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(actionContext, new CancellationToken());
    var id = actionContext.ActionArguments["id"] as string;
}
catch
{
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
}
```

**Note:** You need to make sure you only filter on the parameters that will come from the Request URI, as I have noticed that executing the binding for any parameters that are expected to come from the Request **body** will no longer be passed on to the actual action. i.e. those parameters will be *null*.

This is just to note that you *can* do this, I'd recommend using `GetRouteData()/RouteData` as it is not likely to disrupt the further flow of ASP.NET MVC modelbinding.

```
var routeData = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData;
var id = routeData.Values["id"] as string;
```