# How to get non-static MethodInfo using method name (not in string, not searching in class type)

Tags: c#, reflection, mono, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

Consider following code:

```
public class Test
{
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
    class MethodAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public MethodAttribute(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {

        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {

    }

    [Method(Test.Foo)] //< THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
    public void Boo()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to store MethodInfo instance of Foo in attribute of Boo, but problem is, that I cannot use `Foo` nor `Test.Foo` to get instance of `MethodInfo`. I can **NOT** use `typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo")` (not my decision).

**Important information:**

- Generated error is: error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Test.Foo()'
- I'm coding in Unity3D which is using Mono, not .Net. (more info http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html )
- Windows 7

**Absolutely unimportant information:**

- Why I cannot use `typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo")`: I'm not allowed. It's not in my power to change this decision. I can **not**. (Also, personally, I would like to avoid it anyway as it needs to do some lookup instead of getting statically the data. Also it won't be changed automatically during refactoring and will be checking run-time, not compile-time.)
- Why I want to do this: later in code, I want to create a delegate of Boo() (this time normally, with an instance) and use in special even system or something. Before it's called, this attribute allows to setup method to be called in prepare for main event (it's optional, it can be null) and I know how to create a delegate when I have an object and a method info.
- Why I cannot just provide both delegates when registering or something: because class containing these methods is not always the one who registers to event source, I need to keep the registration code as simple as possible. In other words, I want to avoid situation when person writing method responsible for connecting forgots to add this preparation delegate.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that attributes can contain only compile constant values, so using reflection inside would not compile anyway.

Comment: Isn't pointer to MethodInfo constant? I mean, it's not Python, you cannot change pointer to method in a class. Only if it's virtual, but I want the particular Test.Foo MethodInfo and that should be unchanged whole time, am I wrong? I mean, you can't do something like `Test.Foo = Test.Boo` or `Test.Foo = () => ... ;`...

Comment: I think it is constant per app domain (may be wrong - can some confirm or decline?) - but in c# there is no way to get `MethodInfo` without using `GetMethod`, `GetMethods` or Expression tree.

Comment: Yea, its literally impossible to do what you want to do. Thats why you see attributes referencing methods as string names all the time, not b/c it's pretty but thats just all you can do.

Comment: That's sad, but what can I do. Thanks for the info! (Btw. interesting thing is that the code compiles just fine using .Net, but Unity3D is using Mono.)

Comment: Update: sorry about the its-compiling-in-.net thing, it's my mistake and buggy MonoDevelop. No, it's not compiling even in .Net.

Comment: Attributes are metadata; they are compiled into the assembly at compile-time and do not change during runtime. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10435554/945317

Comment: @cYounes And methods aren't?

Answer (score 0):

use expression :

```
static public class Metadata<T>
{
    static public PropertyInfo Property<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
    {
        var expression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        return expression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
}

var foo = Metadata<Test>.Property(test => test.Foo);
```