# Using a custom attribute on a parameter. Need to read the method parameter in the attribute

Tags: c#

c# .net 6
Using a custom attribute on a parameter.
Need to read the parameters value in the attribute at runtime.
I know its not possible to pass it as a argument to the attribute because its compile time, but I need an idea to overcome this problem!

wish I can do:
public void MyMethod([Custom(parameter)] string parameter)

and use it like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Description;

    public CustomAttribute(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

P.S.
I saw here:
[How to plug method parameters into custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435403/how-to-plug-method-parameters-into-custom-attribute)
last answer is true?

If not, any ideas from you experienced guys?